# C code binding with a Qt gui

Tags: c, qt

My goal is to build an application using Qt library here are the details about my application :

1- I have a code written in C language (this code does the main work of my application)

2 -I want to write a C code using Qt, to allow my application to be able to read and send automaticaly files and UDP frames.

3- and I want to integrate the 1st code within the 2sd code, all that using Qt

4- then I want to build a GUI with Qt which can allow the user of the application to change the parameters of my first code.

5- Finally i want to create a packaging for my application so it can be installed and run easly in Windows OS.

So my question is : is all that can be done using the Qt library ? thank you

Comment: You should create some C function with c++ code inside and declare these functions as `extern "C"`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that you see difference between C and C++ languages.

1. Code written in C - yes, you can use it.
2. C and Qt code to send UDP frames... use C++ and Qt instead.
3. Not sure what you need.
4. Yes, it is possible.
5. Try NSIS to make installers.

Comment: Thank you Petr Bravenec for your answers. 

When you told me to use NSIS to make an installer, you mean by that that's not possible to make it using Qt?

Comment: NSIS is specialized installer which can copy your files to desired place, make changes to registers etc. Installer made by NSIS is very small. If you write installer in Qt, you have to add Qt libraries and the installer itselft will take more then 10 MB.

Comment: It's not a problem if my application take more than 10 MB, I just don't want to make an application that runs slowly or needs extra drivers to run in Windows

Comment: There is yet another problem with Qt: you have to make the installer from scratch. You have to solve problems like zip/unzip all needed files, uninstall and writing to windows registry. All this tasks NSIS makes automatically. All you need is to write a simple script where most of lines is a list of your files. See [NSIS tutorial](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials).

Comment: Thank you a lot, I want know an other thing about Qt, can i use two codes written in two different languages (C and C++) to build an applic